# Have lettered page numbering in Word for a section, then numbered page numbering

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I am writing a report and the standard format appears to be to use Roman numerals for the first section / front matter of the report, and then page numbers starting from 1 for the rest. I can't figure out how to do this in Microsoft Word (for Mac).

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out, actually. If I insert a section break, I can then specify new sets of page numbers, by specifying "1" as my start page, instead of selecting "Start from previous section". This also lets me pick the new format of numbers, instead of letters.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, it's hidden in the bullet+numbering options.

1. Select a header
2. Right-click->Bullets and Numbering
3. Select the Outline Numbered tab
4. Select a numbering format
5. Click Customize (bottom)
6. In the Level or the Preview box, click the heading level you want to
   number
7. Click the expand arrow in the bottom left corner to show the styling
   options
8. Select the header you want to correspond to the numbering level in
   the "link level to style" drop down.

You will have to reapply the style to every existing header in your document.  BE CAREFUL, Word has a ridiculous dialoge box pop-up that asks if you want to update the style or reapply the header.

Adapted from [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-numbers-to-headings-HP005186047.aspx) somewhat helpful MS online help doc.